# Weird double exposure effects on images after sensor cleaning

Tags: shadows, multiple-exposure

I had my Lumix LX-100 sensor cleaned by a professional some time ago. Didn't notice anything special but on Saturday went to my aunt's funeral. Had two cameras with me and quite a few (not all) of the images shot with Lumix came out with really weird effects. See the cropped samples. The shutter speeds were normal. No flash. It also seemed that completely still targets came out ok. Or at least mostly.
I had Lumix in Full AUTO. The distortions may be partial only in some parts of the image and at the back, on the right, on the left...no logic.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I believe the sensor is somehow out of place or something like that.
[image: Sample1]
[image: Sample 2]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it has more to do with the shutter. The camera was in silent mode i.e. only electronic shutter was in use. Haven't tested it with silent mode off yet. Still I believe that the problem was caused by that demanding sensor cleaning operation.

Comment: Why clean a sensor in a compact camera?

Comment: @xenoid the LX-100 has a 4/3’s sensor. It is not an average compact camera. It lacks weather sealing and has a reputation for sucking in dirt via the zoom lens (and just from normal environmental factors).

Answer (score 2):

Double check your modes... There are a couple that take multiple shots and combine them- iHandheld Night Shot, iHDR, HDR, and Multi Exposure. To be safe you might try resetting your camera to factory settings (RESET in the setup menu) and see if that helps.

Comment: Good idea. Just did the factory reset. Good if it helps even if I will never know what caused it. No time to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

My money on a malfunctioning/broken image stabilization, or you didn't wait for the IS to be fully active to take your shots. Given the light you were likely shooting at somewhat low speeds.

To confirm, take a few shots hand-held in low light with the IS enabled and disabled. Shots with the IS disabled should show a continuous motion blur, while those with IS enabled will shop up as above.

Comment: Good suggestion, but 1/80 was probably the slowest shutter speed used. Typivcally 1/125.

Comment: @TimoLaaksosaari what iso and aperture?

Comment: In church: 200/2.2, 400/2.6, 1250/2.3, 640/2.8, 1250/2.8, 

Outside: 200/5.6

Comment: In community hall: 400/2.6, 200/5.0, 200/2.5, 200/2.8 etc...